# Use shortcodes in terms description?

Tags: shortcode

Anyone knows a way of using shortcodes on terms description? This is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work:

```
<?php
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
  $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
?>
```

You could put this in the template of in a hooked functions.

I've cribbed this from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content), where the intention is to write content from `get_the_content()` (raw) in an equivalent way to `the_content()` (amongst other things: parsed shortcodes).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's only code that is needed, but Hybrid has this filter mod for such:

```
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
```

If this doesn't work I'll try to go over code more thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks Rarst, Unfortunately that filter did not work... :( Cheers

Comment: Can't find anything else... What do you get with this line added? Raw unprocessed shortcode?